# How do I make the 'Shut Down the Computer' window be monochrome?

Tags: icons, shutdown, window

When I hit the power button of my computer, a window titled 'Shut Down the Computer' appears. It gives a few options, including shutting down or restarting.

This window is different following the context I hit the power button :

- when logged in and seeing my desktop, it includes colourful icons (red for shutting down, for example).
- when I am not logged in yet, the icons are monochrome and a little bit more stylized.

I clearly prefer the last type of icons : how do I set them as default whatever the context of use of the 'Shut Down the Computer' window ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your icon set in appearance preferences to LoginIcons.  This will adopt the icons from the login screen, and also change the rest of your system icons to the Humanity set.

If you want to use the default Ambiance icons instead of the Humanity ones:

1. Create a local copy of the LoginIcons set:

   `cp -R /usr/share/icons/LoginIcons ~/.local/share/icons`
2. open the newly-copied ~/.local/share/icons/LoginIcons/index.theme in gedit and change the Inherits line (line 4) to `Inherits=ubuntu-mono-dark,gnome,hicolor`
3. Change the Name line (line 2) to something unique; then select your newly named icon set in appearance preferences.

Comment: Thanks ! The right 2nd step is to write "Inherits=ubuntu-mono-light,gnome,hicolor" (notice the lower case letters). It changed a little bit more than expected, but I know now how to fix it !

Comment: For example my hard drives are now represented as circled snow stars ... At least I deleted the undesired icons of the folder I created in ~/.local/share/icons

Comment: The shutdown window uses the hard drive icon to represent "hibernate" and the refresh icon to represent "restart," so I don't think that there's any way to change those without changing the shutdown screen.